# Custom convert lead button using code

Tags: leads

I used this link to help me create a custom conver button on the lead so that way I could default check "Do not create new opportunity upon conversion". The button is created and from what I can tell, is right but I am stuck when it says to code the button. It gives 2 lines of code, but where does that code go? I am sure I am missing something easy, but I am pretty new to coding so forgive my silly question.

http://cloudyk.com/salesforce/salesforce-lead-conversion-do-not-create-opportunity-by-default/

Answer (score 1):

The code is the JavaScript your button executes. When you are on the Custom Button screen and select `OnClick JavaScript` as your content source you would enter that code (as one line) into the editor below.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks so much for your help!